# how to prevent php fwrite() from overwriting a line of text on file?

Tags: php, fwrite, overwrite

I have extracted following lines of code from my script.

```
    $i=0;
    $j=0;
    $fp=fopen('C:\xampp\htdocs\Lib_auto_project\Deleted_Records\delete_log.sql','a+');// File where the string is to be written
    foreach($_POST as $temp)//repeat for all the values passed from the form
    {
        if($j==0)
          {     
               $result_set=$mysqli->query("select * from {$_SESSION['table_name_1']} where Copyid=$temp");
               $result_set=$result_set->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH);    
               ++$j;

           }
        if($temp!='Drop')// Drop is simply the value of submit buttom
         {
            $date=mysql_query("select now() as current_date_time") or die(mysql_error());
            $date=mysql_fetch_array($date,MYSQL_BOTH);
            $result="\n"."INSERT INTO delete_book_log  // this is the string begining with line break and followed by sql insert statement
                          VALUES(
                                 '{$result_set["Bid"]}',
                                 '$temp',
                                 '{$result_set["Name"]}',
                                 '{$result_set["Publication"]}',
                                 '{$result_set["ISBN"]}',
                                 '{$result_set["Author"]}',
                                 '{$result_set["Edition"]}',
                                 'in',
                                 '{$result_set["Book_Baseid"]}',
                                 '{$date['current_date_time']}'
                                 );";
              fflush($fp);
              fwrite($fp,$result);
              $mysqli->query("Delete from {$_SESSION['table_name_1']} where copyid=$temp");
              $i++;
          }

      }
      fclose($fp);
```

![screen shot]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOzSj.jpg

As you can see from the screen-shot, when one or more of the records are selected and the drop button is clicked, I want the records to be deleted from the database but want the corresponding sql insert statements to be written into a `file(C:\xampp\htdocs\Lib_auto_project\Deleted_Records\delete_log.sql)`.For that to happen I have written the above piece of code. Now the problem is when I select the records and drop them all goes as desired. When I do the same any other instant I want similar sql insert strings, stored as shown above in $result, appended to the end of the `file(C:\xampp\htdocs\Lib_auto_project\Deleted_Records\delete_log.sql)`. This does not quite happen. Rather the previously written strings get overwritten by the new one.
I have tried it over and over but only the recent strings get overwrite the old ones.

Comment: you use mysqli without using prepared statment lol

Comment: have you tried `fopen('C:\xampp ...','ab')` - there are some funny things happening in Windows without the `b`

Comment: @Eugen RieckNo: I just gave it a try, it does not help.

Comment: "where Copyid=$temp" - has Copyid a unique constraint, i.e. can there be only 0 or 1 records per iteration? And can you please explain what you're trying to achieve (including the conditions)?

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify it in greater detail, and have posted a screen shot either. Now looking at the screen shot it might have been clear to you that you cannot drop records without selecting anything. So there has to at-least one record.

Comment: You should escape `"` (double quotes) in generating results and `$date=mysql_query("select now() as current_date_time") or die(mysql_error());` if you cannot `date( 'Y-m-d h:i:s')` for some extravagant reasons you always can put mysql before the loop. Man god is killing kittens because of you.

Answer (score 1):

It's nice that php says in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) that `a+` (using `a` should be just enough for you):

> Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

but try to run this code (called `test.php`):

```php
<?php    
$fp = fopen( 'test.php', 'a+') or die( 'Cannot open!');
echo 'Pos: ' . ftell($fp) ."\n";
echo fgets($fp);
echo 'Pos: ' . ftell($fp) ."\n";
fclose( $fp);
```

it'll generate this output:

```
Pos: 0
<?php
Pos: 6
```

You may either use [`fseek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php):

```php
fseek( $fp, 0, SEEK_END);
```

Or use [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) with proper parameters:

```php
file_put_contents( $file, $string, FILE_APPEND);
```

And don't forget to check your file permissions and whether file was opened successfully by  code like this:

```
if( !$fp){ 
    die( 'File cannot be opened!');
}
```

Comment: This didn't work either. But when I changed the file to be written to a new test.sql file everything works alright. But the original file was a mysqldump file. Does that make any difference? I guess the issue is with the file being a dump file.

Comment: @Jiwan try using this instead: `fopen( ..., 'a') or die('Cannot open file!');` **that** may be a problem :), edited answer, take a look.

Comment: I have a feeling that the issue is with dump file. It works fine with a different file.  That will do. Gosh!!!!! Enough Cheese off.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use file_get_contents and file_put_contents instead of fwrite, and append your queries to array or string:

```
$fp=file_get_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\Lib_auto_project\Deleted_Records\delete_log.sql');// File where the string is to be written
foreach($_POST as $temp)//repeat for all the values passed from the form
{
    if($j==0)
      {     
           $result_set=$mysqli->query("select * from {$_SESSION['table_name_1']} where Copyid=$temp");
           $result_set=$result_set->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH);    
           ++$j;

       }
    if($temp!='Drop')// Drop is simply the value of submit buttom
     {
        $date=mysql_query("select now() as current_date_time") or die(mysql_error());
        $date=mysql_fetch_array($date,MYSQL_BOTH);
        $result="\n"."INSERT INTO delete_book_log  // this is the string begining with line break and followed by sql insert statement
                      VALUES(
                             '{$result_set["Bid"]}',
                             '$temp',
                             '{$result_set["Name"]}',
                             '{$result_set["Publication"]}',
                             '{$result_set["ISBN"]}',
                             '{$result_set["Author"]}',
                             '{$result_set["Edition"]}',
                             'in',
                             '{$result_set["Book_Baseid"]}',
                             '{$date['current_date_time']}'
                             );";
          $fp .= $result . "\r\n";
          $mysqli->query("Delete from {$_SESSION['table_name_1']} where copyid=$temp");
          $i++;
      }

  }
  file_put_contents($fp);
```

Comment: I did try file_put_contents, it didn't work either. But I think having all the statements in an array, and writing the array to the file might help. I will definitely try it and let you know. In the mean time please do tell if you think there is any other to get around this.

Comment: Seems like I woke up on the wrong side of the bed today, nothing is working at all. Any further suggestion.. I am really stuck.

Comment: This happened !! say the loop iterated for 3 times and three lines were written into the file. But when the code is re-executed previously written lines have been overwritten. This is not what I desire of. I need the later lines to be written not overwritten over the previous lines.

Comment: -1 for a) naming text variable `$fp` b) creating long text and outputting in one place (in this context it's just wrong) and OS you're using **SHOULD** provide file cache so `fwrite()` doesn't have immediate affect for disk  c) suggesting `file_put_contents()` without mentioning `FILE_APPEND`

Comment: And at the end, `file_put_contents()` to what file exactly? :)